# PHP 7+ & PDO SQLSRV charset issue

Tags: php, pdo, character-encoding, sqlsrv

PHP 7.2.8

[image: PHP 7.2.8]

PHP 5.6.37

[image: PHP 5.6.37]

Same code, different version of PHP. Many have the same problem than I have read.
Did someone finally find the solution?

Thanx in advance.

PS: I have tried with Medoo lib and without lib. Same problem.

Connection File:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php';

use Medoo\Medoo;

/* Connection to lin2db database */
$lin2db = new Medoo([
    'database_type' => 'mssql',
    'database_name' => $CONFIG['lin2db'],
    'server' => $CONFIG['MSSQL_addr'],
    'username' => $CONFIG['username'],
    'password' => $CONFIG['password'],
    'charset' => 'utf8'
]);
```

Query:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../engine/DB_connection.php';

GLOBAL $lin2db;

$rows = $lin2db->select("user_auth", [
    "account",
    "password"
], [
    "account" => 'builder'
]);

var_dump($rows);
```

**Solution:**

var_dump(bin2hex($rows));

Comment: Try this `ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');`

Comment: And would you mind sharing that code? Which other problem reports of that case have you found - can you link them?

Comment: @AramMnatsakanyan, 
I have tried it. Not working.

Comment: @NicoHaase i have edit the post.

Comment: Run a phpinfo() side by side for the two versions of PHP. See if there is a different in libraries that could give a clue.

Comment: Solution: var_dump(bin2hex($rows));

It works!